# Codeigniter - Multiple database prefixes

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I'm in process to migrate an old webapp to codeigniter, everything looks good other then that the database has 3 kind of tables with different table prefixes.

- the app's native tables use `mci_` as prefix
- tables which hold inter departmental data (kind off) use `mdept_`
- and tables handling non-native data use `mext_` as prefix

now as I understand we can set one prefix for entire database

```
'hostname' => DB_HOST,
'username' => DB_USER,
'password' => DB_PASS,
'database' => DB_NAME,
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => 'mci_',
```

and query builder will use `mci_` for all tables.

My question is, is there a way to use rest of the 2 prefixes (`mdept_`, `mext_`) with query builder rather then having the direct approach `db->query`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Solution #1:**

You can set `$this->db->dbprefix = "mdept_"` before `$this->db->select()...get();`. But this will work if there is only one table in the query. And if there are other queries below, then you also need to redefine `dbprefix` again.

**Solution #2:**

Add for `mdept_...` and `mext_...` tables the prefix `mci_`. I.e `mci_mdept_users`. No need to change the database config, redefine the prefix, just specify the table names in the queries along with the old "prefixes".

**Solution #3:**

Delete prefix in config at all: `'dbprefix' => ''`, and use full table names with prefixes in queries.

**Solution #4. The best solution of these, in my opinion**

Add a view with the `mci_` prefix to your database: `CREATE VIEW mci_old_mdept_users AS SELECT * FROM mdept_users;`. All that the view will do is to get data from a table that you cannot rename. And in your application you can write simply: `$this->db->get('old_mdept_users');`.

**Solution #5.** If all queries use tables with the same prefixes

Divide tables into 3 databases. Add these databases in the config:

```
$db['default'] = array(
    ...
    'dbprefix'     => 'mci_',
    ...
);
$db['mdept'] = array(
    ...
    'dbprefix'     => 'mdept_',
    ...
);
$db['mext'] = array(
    ...
    'dbprefix'     => 'mext_',
    ...
);
```

Add other connections in MY_Model:

```
protected function connect_mdept_db()
{
    $this->mdept_db = $this->load->database('mdept', TRUE);
}
```

Use these connections:

```
$this->connect_mdept_db();
$this->mdept_db->get("users"); // uses "mdept_users" table
```

Comment: can't change prefix (solution 2) as specially the non-native `mext_` tables are being populated external data by foreign scripts I have no control over! I think with solution 1 you are suggesting to set `dbprefix` each time I have to use those tables right?

Comment: @Anupam Yes, that's right. If there are many such places, then Solution 3 or Solution 4 is probably better, I added in the answer above.

Comment: don't like solution 3, yet maybe the only way if I want to use active records! About solution 4, not practical in case since there are 20+ `mdept_` tables and 65+ `mext_` ones!! yeah it's that crazy!

Comment: @Anupam If you want use Active Record AND in one query you have tables with different queries AND don't want use views - yes, only Solution 3. If all queries use tables with the same prefixes, then Solution 5 may suit you, added above.

Comment: Yep I've thought of setting multiple db configs, I'm actually headed that way. Thanks for confirming the same :D